# How to add Views dynamically and set their Id's

Tags: android, sketchware

I want to build sketch app with a lot of Views e.g Button, Textview,EditText e.t.c, So have create a panel for Views list, and I want to add each view to work place when I pressed on them and I want their ids be created automatically and How could I make and find ids' for these Views so user can be able to edit them?